# Better search method for rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So currently im trying to match two tables together,

The current way i've been doing it is this:

```
  date = row.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  time = if row.time.present?
           row.time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
         else
           '00:00:00'
       end
  eventname = row.eventname.gsub('&', 'and')
  ticketmaster = Ticketmasters.find_by('product_name ILIKE ? AND delivery_time ILIKE ? AND valid_from = ? AND promotional_text ILIKE ?', "%#{row.eventname}%", time, date, "%#{row.eventvenuename}%")
  if ticketmaster.blank?
    ticketmaster = Ticketmasters.find_by('product_name ILIKE ? AND valid_from = ? AND promotional_text ILIKE ?', "%#{row.eventname}%", date, "%#{row.eventvenuename}%")
    if ticketmaster.blank?
      ticketmaster = Ticketmasters.find_by('product_name ILIKE ? AND valid_from = ?', "%#{row.eventname}%", date)
      if ticketmaster.blank?
        ticketmaster = Ticketmasters.find_by('product_name ILIKE ? AND delivery_time ILIKE ? AND valid_from = ? AND promotional_text ILIKE ?', "%#{eventname}%", time, date, "%#{row.eventvenuename}%")
        if ticketmaster.blank?
          ticketmaster = Ticketmasters.find_by('product_name ILIKE ? AND valid_from = ? AND promotional_text ILIKE ?', "%#{eventname}%", date, "%#{row.eventvenuename}%")
          if ticketmaster.blank?
            ticketmaster = Ticketmasters.find_by('product_name ILIKE ? AND valid_from = ?', "%#{eventname}%", date)
          end
          if ticketmaster.blank?
            eventname = row.eventname.gsub('Disney Presents ', '')
            ticketmaster = Ticketmasters.find_by('product_name ILIKE ? AND valid_from = ?', "%#{eventname}%", date)
           end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

This is just to find the event.. I am sure this isn't the best method to find the event!!

I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing it? if so what would i need to do? is there any gems or anything i could use to do this

Thanks

Sam

Comment: I didn't fully read your code, but when you say "match two tables", you should be using JOIN Tables, search for that.

Comment: I may have just said that wrong, i need to have the two tables work together, if you look in the code you can see that there is alot going on to search the event table against the ticketmaster table. I was wondering if there was anyway to sped this up/simplify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can modify your `Ticketmasters` class, then you could make those queries into scopes, something like:

```
class Ticketmasters
  scope :search_promotional_text, -> (text)         { where("promotional_text ILIKE ?", "%#{text}%") }
  scope :search_delivery_time,    -> (time)         { where("delivery_time ILIKE ?", time)}
  scope :search_product_name,     -> (product_name) { where("product_name ILIKE ?", "%#{product_name}%") }
  scope :search_valid_from,       -> (date)         { where("valid_from = ?", date) }

end
```

Then, you could add a class method called something like `search_by` that accepts a `hash` of arguments. Something like:

```
class Ticketmasters
  scope :search_promotional_text, -> (text)         { where("promotional_text ILIKE ?", "%#{text}%") }
  scope :search_delivery_time,    -> (time)         { where("delivery_time ILIKE ?", time)}
  scope :search_product_name,     -> (product_name) { where("product_name ILIKE ?", "%#{product_name}%") }
  scope :search_valid_from,       -> (date)         { where("valid_from = ?", date) }

  class << self

    def search_by(search_options={})
      search_result = nil
      search_options.each do |k,v|
        search_result = (search_result ? search_result : self).send("search_#{k}",v)
      end
      search_result
    end

  end

end
```

The `search_by` method is simply chaining together queries based on the arguments passed in the `options` hash.

Then, you could do something like:

```
ticketmaster = nil
search_hsh = {
  delivery_time: row.time.present? ? row.time.strftime('%H:%M:%S') : '00:00:00', 
  valid_from: row.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), 
  promotional_text: row.eventvenuename
}
[row.eventname, row.eventname.gsub('&', 'and')].each do |use_event_name|
  search_hsh[:product_name] = use_event_name
  ticketmaster ||= Ticketmasters.search_by(search_hsh).first
  ticketmaster ||= Ticketmasters.search_by(search_hsh.except(:delivery_time)).first
  ticketmaster ||= Ticketmasters.search_by(search_hsh.except(:delivery_time, :promotional_text).first
end
search_hsh[:product_name] = row.eventname.gsub('Disney Presents ', '')
ticketmaster ||= Ticketmasters.search_by(search_hsh.except(:delivery_time, :promotional_text).first
```

Now, to be clear, this is using the EXACT SAME search strategy that you are currently using. So, depending on how you define "better", this is no better. However, this does reduce redundancy and, IMO, makes it a bit clearer what your search strategy actually is.